# All-Encompassing Dark Theme for Colourblind people?

Tags: themes

I'm totally new to android so I'm not sure if it works like this - but is there an add-on or something like that that I can get to make all app's "dark theme"?

I have a Oneplus 5 and I used the default dark theme but obviously things like Google Chrome and facebook are white backgrounds, which are very difficult for my colourblind-ness. Will I have to download add ons for every app I want in a dark theme? Or is there a sort of "all-encompassing" add-on I can get?

Comment: This isn't really possible as of now. However Android 8.0 has theming support, so once OnePlus launches it you can look for dark themes (won't work on all apps though).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can go to `Settings`->`Accessibility`->`Color Space Correction`. Try that, and see if it solves the issue for you. I'm not colorblind, so it is kind of hard for me to see if it works as expected for you...

I got it from [here](https://hackernoon.com/discover-how-to-fix-your-color-blind-problems-on-android-devices-with-the-color-correction-mode-66e1c3949bf6)

It is available since Android L, according to [this site](https://www.androidcentral.com/android-l-includes-new-display-modes-color-blind-users)

Comment: Hi, not really what I'm after. I'm not looking for colour correction, I'm looking for white on black themes, like the one that I can choose in the Oneplus settings, but for external apps too. I assume that will need some sort of interference with the actual style code of the application, so I presume the answer is 'no', but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On my Android 7 phone, there is a relevant setting under Accessibility -> Color inversion. However, this requires quite a bit of tuning to be usable, since it will affect all icons, wallpapers etc. Some apps like camera or video players will never look right.

The best way to use it is to put its icon in the quick settings menu and activate or deactivate as needed:

[image: IMG:]